# Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ListView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: vb.net

i'm trying to export list view item to excel sheet, every thing work perfect 
but when I'm trying to do this in background worker i face this error :

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ListView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

i dint know how to fix this , please help me :)

this is my code :

```
Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
    Try
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx"
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Excel File"
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            If saveFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
                PictureBox1.Visible = True
                BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    saveExcelFile(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    PictureBox1.Visible = False
    MessageBox.Show("DONE !!")
End Sub

Public Sub saveExcelFile(ByVal FileName As String)
    'Try
    Dim xls As New Excel.Application
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    xls.Workbooks.Add()
    sheet = xls.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Dim row As Integer = 1
    Dim col As Integer = 1
    For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
        sheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = Me.ListView1.Columns(i).Text
    Next
    For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1 ' here the ERROR !!
            sheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
        Next
    Next

    row += 1
    col = 1

    ' for the header 
    sheet.Rows(1).Font.Name = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
    sheet.Rows(1).Font.size = 16
    sheet.Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    sheet.Rows(1).HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
    Dim mycol As System.Drawing.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#20b2aa")
    sheet.Rows(1).Font.color = mycol
    ' for all the sheet without header
    sheet.Range("a2", "z1000").Font.Name = "Arial"
    sheet.Range("a2", "z1000").Font.Size = 14
    sheet.Range("a2", "z1000").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter

    sheet.Range("A1:X1").EntireColumn.AutoFit()
    sheet.Range("A1:X1").EntireRow.AutoFit()

    xls.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(FileName)
    xls.Workbooks.Close()
    xls.Quit()
    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    'End Try
End Sub
```

hello Enigmativity ...

i do what you say but i have small error :

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Noor Phone.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to access the file. Try one of the following actions:

• Make sure that the selected folder.

• Make sure that the folder that contains the file is not read-only.

• Make sure the file name does not contain one of the following codes: <>? []: | Or *

• Make sure the file name and path name does not contain more than 128 characters.

this is my code after editing:

```
 Private Class BgwData
    Public FileName As String
    Public Headers As String()
    Public Data As String()()
End Class
Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
    'Try

    Dim data As New BgwData() With _
{ _
.FileName = SaveFileDialog1.FileName, _
.Headers = _
Me.ListView1.Columns _
    .Cast(Of System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)() _
    .Select(Function(ch) ch.Name) _
    .ToArray(), _
.Data = _
Me.ListView1.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem)() _
    .Select(Function(lvi) lvi.SubItems _
            .Cast(Of ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem)() _
            .Select(Function(lvsi) lvsi.Text) _
            .ToArray()) _
    .ToArray() _
}

    'BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(data)
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx"
    SaveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Excel File"
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        If SaveFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
            PictureBox1.Visible = True
            'BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(data)

        End If
    End If
    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    'End Try
End Sub
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    'saveExcelFile(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    saveExcelFile(CType(e.Argument, BgwData))
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    PictureBox1.Visible = False
    MessageBox.Show("DONE !!")
End Sub
Private Sub saveExcelFile(ByVal data As BgwData)
    'Public Sub saveExcelFile(ByVal FileName As String)
    'Try
    Dim xls As New Excel.Application
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    xls.Workbooks.Add()
    sheet = xls.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'Dim row As Integer = 1
    'Dim col As Integer = 1
    'For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
    '    sheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = Me.ListView1.Columns(i).Text
    'Next
    'For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
    '    For j = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1 ' here the ERROR !!
    '        sheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
    '    Next
    'Next

    Dim row As Integer = 1
    Dim col As Integer = 1
    For i = 0 To data.Headers.Length - 1
        sheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = data.Headers(i)
    Next
    For i = 0 To data.Data.Length - 1
        For j = 0 To data.Data(i).Length - 1
            sheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = data.Data(i)(j)
        Next
    Next

    row += 1
    col = 1

    ' for the header 
    sheet.Rows(1).Font.Name = "Microsoft Sans Serif"
    sheet.Rows(1).Font.size = 16
    sheet.Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    sheet.Rows(1).HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
    Dim mycol As System.Drawing.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#20b2aa")
    sheet.Rows(1).Font.color = mycol
    ' for all the sheet without header
    sheet.Range("a2", "z1000").Font.Name = "Arial"
    sheet.Range("a2", "z1000").Font.Size = 14
    sheet.Range("a2", "z1000").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter

    sheet.Range("A1:X1").EntireColumn.AutoFit()
    sheet.Range("A1:X1").EntireRow.AutoFit()

    'xls.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(FileName)
    xls.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(data.FileName)'**HERE THE ERROR**
    xls.Workbooks.Close()
    xls.Quit()

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xls)

    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    'End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always make sure that when you access elements of the UI that you do so on the UI thread otherwise you can get the error you're experiencing.

The easiest way to avoid this issue is to separate out the code that reads the data from the UI and the code that writes your Excel file.

First start by defining a simple class to hold your data:

```
Private Class BgwData
    Public FileName As String
    Public Headers As String()
    Public Data As String()()
End Class
```

I defined this inside the form class as it doesn't need to be exposed outside of the form.

Now the code that calls the background worker needs to change so that an instance of `BgwData` is created, populated with the data from the `ListView`, as well as the file name, and sent to the worker as its argument.

```
Dim data As New BgwData() With _
{ _
    .FileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName, _
    .Headers = _
        Me.ListView1.Columns _
            .Cast(Of System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)() _
            .Select(Function(ch) ch.Name) _
            .ToArray(), _
    .Data = _
        Me.ListView1.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem)() _
            .Select(Function(lvi) lvi.SubItems _
                    .Cast(Of ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem)() _
                    .Select(Function(lvsi) lvsi.Text) _
                    .ToArray()) _
            .ToArray() _
}

BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(data)
```

This code runs in the `PictureBox2_Click` so is still on the UI thread.

The `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork` method changes slightly to call `saveExcelFile` like this:

```
saveExcelFile(CType(e.Argument, BgwData))
```

The signature for `saveExcelFile` changes to `Private Sub saveExcelFile(ByVal data As BgwData)`

And the code that populates the spreadsheet becomes:

```
Dim row As Integer = 1
Dim col As Integer = 1
For i = 0 To data.Headers.Length - 1
    sheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = data.Headers(i)
Next
For i = 0 To data.Data.Length - 1
    For j = 0 To data.Data(i).Length - 1
        sheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = data.Data(i)(j)
    Next
Next
```

And, of course, there is a small change to the `SaveAs` method call to become:

```
xls.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(data.FileName)
```

Also, as a side note, do keep in mind that you need release your COM objects after you use them too:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xls);
```

Comment: Also, you probably need to keep in mind that anytime you use a COM component like `xls.Workbooks.Add()` or `xls.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` that you should take an intermediate reference to the `Workbooks` and `ActiveWorkbook` to then later call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(...)` on those references too.

Comment: hello , first thanks for this amazing answer , really man you are awesome :)
but i sill have small error , i done everything you say but i have error , i updated my question can you help me with this please @Enigmativity

Comment: @RabeeaQabaha - Try putting in the other `ReleaseComObject(...)` calls as per my comment above. You may need to do a full PC restart to clear your COM objects from memory when testing.

Comment: I've restart my Computer , but the problem still :(
what do you mean , what i need to do with "Try putting in the other ReleaseComObject(...) calls as per my comment above. " ?@Enigmativity

Comment: @RabeeaQabaha - You can't do a double `.` to reference COM objects. So `sheet = xls.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` needs to be `var wb = xls.ActiveWorkbook; sheet = wb.ActiveSheet;` then you can release the `wb` object. You need to do this for every "double reference". Every time you test and something goes wrong you may need to reboot before testing your code again, otherwise the error may prevent the next run working even though you've fixed the code.

Comment: still the same error :(
here the error : "xls.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(data.FileName)"
i don't know what to do :( @Enigmativity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76584/discussion-between-rabeea-qabaha-and-enigmativity).

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer all what i need is to add this line of code in the load form

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

thanks for helping